# Internal navigation is not working in pdf generated from html in puppeteer in nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, pdf, puppeteer, internal-link

I generated a pdf from html using puppeteer but it is not showing clickable links for navigation inside the pdf.
I am doing this using nodejs.

This is my html sample code. Is there any way so that i can add clickable internal navigation in pdf?

[Html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsryE.jpg)

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.